# Deleting files and the folder containg files automatically after 24 hours

Tags: php, time

I am having issues with deleting the files and the folder containing the files using PHP. I want to delete the folder on my server and the files containing folder automatically just after 24 hours. I am creating the folder to save the uploaded documents. I try some code too but it is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is why I try:-

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/Docs/'.$foldername;
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($filesss = readdir($handle))) {
        if ((time()-filectime($path.'/'.$filesss)) < 86400) {  // 86400 = 60*60*24

           unlink($path.'/'.$filesss);


        }
    }
  }
```

I try this code but it is not working for me the way I want. This code deletes my files at the moment. but I want to delete these files after 24 hours and also the folder containing these files I want to delete that folder after 24 hours too. Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: May be just inverse ineqaility sign? (time() - filectime() < 86400 get a true for the files that _younger_ than 24 hours)

Answer (score 2):

Create Cron File and write Below Code.

```
function Delete($path)
{
    if (is_dir($path) === true) {
        $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    } else if (is_file($path) === true) {
        return unlink($path);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: where did you specify the time ??

Comment: One more question will it be possible without creating a  Cron  file ?

Comment: cron time set midnight 12:00 AM

Comment: without cron file it's not execute automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131561/discussion-between-pranay-sute-and-sujal-patel).

Comment: well, if this is being run every 24 hours, it will simply delete everything it finds. even if a file/dir is created 1 second before the cron runs, it will get deleted. you need to check the age of the file/dir anyway and delete them only if they're older than 24h.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((time() - filectime($path.'/'.$filesss)) >= 86400)
```

You need to check if the difference between "now" and the time when the file was created is more than 24 hours, not less.

Comment: it is not working as you can see i have it already in my code.

Comment: @PranaySute You're using `<` operator. Use `>=` to check if the time difference is equal to or more than 24h.

Comment: ohh well i will try this one and let you know.!!